# IIS manager. Open web site outside the server computer

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, iis-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it Possible to view my apache server (local host) from home or remote computer that is outside my LAN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/111614/is-it-possible-to-view-my-apache-server-local-host-from-home-or-remote-compute)

Today i cofigured web server on Windows server 2003 i uploaded my site on C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysite
local host working good

In IIS Manger default web site is running

How i can open my web site (C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysite) from another computer?

Im doing it first and if i asked fool question please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `http://[IP address of the server]/mysite` into the browser on another computer? This usually works...

Comment: I tried of course but 'internet explorer cannot display page' getting this error. I added global IP of server in web site identification descritpion (IIS manager) tcp port 80 is open. added new virtual direcotry. but result is same. null

Comment: Sounds like it's broken then.

Comment: What is broken?

Comment: I've no idea - you've given extremely little detail to work with, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I dont know which details would be useful you say it i can provide

Comment: How did you upload the site onto the server? Is it a static site, or a .NET (or other) application? What version of .NET if it's an application? Does it show up in IIS manager? What is the default document set for the directory? What is the default document for your application? Do you have a firewall in place on the server? Can you ping the server? Is your client and the server on the same domain? What if you put the `http://[server ip]/mysite` into IE on the server itself? Do you have any odd proxy settings on your browser? Have you tried a different browser? etc. etc. etc. etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ip-address or hostname of the iis server where you have uploaded the site into another machine.

That is http://ip-address-server  or http://hostname-server.